# iPhone in app youtube playing

Tags: iphone, youtube

I had used the links in fmt_url_map, but it does not work. I want to trigger the video directly without the original youtube app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply embedd the video in webView

```
NSString *embedHTML = @"\
    <html><head>\
    <style type=\"text/css\">\
    body {\
    background-color: transparent;\
    color: white;\
    }\
    </style>\
    </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
    <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
    width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
    </body></html>";

NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML,url, 64.0, 64.0];
[wbView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

where wbView is your webview in which video will be embedded &
url is your video url.

Hope it helps

Comment: That works! But what about playing the video in Landscape mode?

Comment: looks like code was found here:  http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/audio-video/how-to-play-youtube-videos-within-an-application